# ffmpeg - Compare 2 AVFrames data

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I have 2 AVFrame pointers

```
float compareFrame(AVFrame* firstFrame, AVFrame* secondFrame)
{
    int i,j;
    const size_t image_size = height * width;
    size_t diffbytes = 0;

    for (i=0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j < width; j++) {
            size_t coord = firstFrame->linesize[0]*i + j;
            diffbytes += !!(firstFrame->data[0][coord] ^ secondFrame->data[0][coord]);
        }
    }
    const float percent_diff = (diffbytes / (float)image_size)*100.0;
    return percent_diff;
}
```

But it seems not correct when compare the 2 same AVFrames. How to determine two AVFrames have exactly the same data or not?

Comment: I got the compare method from this [link](https://github.com/Flameeyes/unpaper/blob/master/tests/compare-image.c)

Comment: The method seem to be fine. It is easy to verify if it is working and debug if not. Init frame and pass pointer to it to both first and second argument in this function.

Comment: Are you sure "firstFrame->linesize[0]" is same as "secondFrame->linesize[0]"?

Comment: the linesize[0] of two frames are the same. I also dump the frames to image files and compare them with `diff` command, and it shows that 2 images are the same while the method does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your definition of "working correctly" is poorly defined. Basically, the question is: what are you comparing and what do you consider different?

First, your function: it only compares an 8-bit plane of Y data, i.e. this only works for 8-bit planar data formats. What is the format of your `AVFrame`? (Check `AVFrame->format`!) If it is not something like `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P`, `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P` or `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV444P`, this function won't work.

Secondly, the algorithm: if all pixels got one value darker, the difference value from this function will be 100%, but the image still looks approximately the same. So, is the value of 100.0% what you want for this scenario? Why not use a more generally accepted metric for image similarity, such as [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) or the related expression [PSNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio)? There's also alternative metrics, e.g. [SSIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity).

If you don't like any of this, and you want to use your code, can you please define what you mean when you say it's not "working correctly"? What input did you use and what was the actual and expected output?

Comment: The format of AVFrame is `PIX_FMT_RGB24`. I mean that i'm just need to compare the binary content of the frame. I tried to dump the content of AVFrame to `ppm` image file and used `diff` command (on Linux) to compare 2 image. While `diff` shows that 2 images are the same, the algorithm above gives approx. ~10%, and it does not have fixed value (the value change when I run many times with the same input)

Comment: First, you're only comparing 1/3rd of each line if the image is RGB24. As for your result, I'm pretty sure that linesize for image1 and image2 is not identical or something like that. Debug it, figure out when the diff becomes non-zero, and why that happened. That's what debugging is all about.

Comment: The 2 linesizes are the same, I have debug the function and saw that the method use to loop the AVFrames are not correct. Do you know how to compare each pixel's value of 2 `AVFrame` with `PIX_FMT_RGB24` format?